# VBA error in Excel: Invalid Use of Property

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the below code in `CommandButton_Click()`, but it gives the following error:

> Compile Error:Invalid Use of Property.

```
Public Sub SectorNAme()
  Dim score As String, result As Integer
  Dim a_counter As Integer

  For a_counter = 1 To 473
    score = Range("AB" + a_counter).Value

    If score = "Technology & FM" Then
      result = "25"
    ElseIf score = "Operating Equipment & Supplies" Then
      result = "26"
    ElseIf score = "Interiors & Design" Then
      result = "27"
    ElseIf score = "Outdoor & Resort Experience" Then
      result = "28"
    ElseIf score = "HORECA" Then
      result = "29"
    ElseIf score = "Retail & Franchise" Then
      result = "30"
    ElseIf score = "Design" Then
      result = "33"
    ElseIf score = "Health & Fitness Eqpts, P&S" Then
      result = "32"
    ElseIf score = "Recreational Fun & Adventure" Then
      result = "31"
    Else
      result = "35"

    Range("AC" + a_counter).Value

    End If
  Next a_counter
End Sub
```

Please help me find a solution.

Answer (score 6):

You have a few small problems:

1. The error you're getting is at:

   ```
   Range("AC" + a_counter).Value
   ```

   I assume you meant to do:

   ```
   Range("AC" + a_counter).Value = result
   ```
2. This: `Range("AB" + a_counter)` and this: `Range("AC" + a_counter)` should be using `&` and not `+` to concatenate the strings, otherwise you get a type mismatch, i.e.: `Range("AB" & a_counter)` and `Range("AC" & a_counter)`.
3. I've just edited your question and, with better indentation, I also noticed that your `End If` is **after** `Range("AC" + a_counter).Value`, which is wrong. It should be **before** that, otherwise your result will only be assigned in the `Else` case and not for any others.

So, your final code should look like this:

```
Public Sub SectorName()

  Dim score As String, result As Integer
  Dim a_counter As Integer

  For a_counter = 1 To 473
    score = Range("AB" & a_counter).Value

    If score = "Technology & FM" Then
      result = "25"
    ElseIf score = "Operating Equipment & Supplies" Then
      result = "26"
    ElseIf score = "Interiors & Design" Then
      result = "27"
    ElseIf score = "Outdoor & Resort Experience" Then
      result = "28"
    ElseIf score = "HORECA" Then
      result = "29"
    ElseIf score = "Retail & Franchise" Then
      result = "30"
    ElseIf score = "Design" Then
      result = "33"
    ElseIf score = "Health & Fitness Eqpts, P&S" Then
      result = "32"
    ElseIf score = "Recreational Fun & Adventure" Then
      result = "31"
    Else
      result = "35"
    End If

    Range("AC" & a_counter).Value = result
  Next a_counter

End Sub
```

This should now work as you expect.